# Check if cookie exists, and if not open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-cookies

I have a cookie set when client closes the modal, what I need is, the modal should only open when cookie is not set. My cookie is set for secure connection only, do you think that javascript can't access the cookie because of SSL? Thank you in advance.

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
var c_value = document.cookie,
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1) c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1) {
    c_value = null;
} else {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
    if (c_end == -1) {
        c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
}
return c_value;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var acookie = getCookie("mycookie");
if (!acookie) {

        var count=-1; // initially -1 as we are having a delay of 1000ms

        var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

        function timer()
        {
            count=count+1;
            if (count >=6) //+1 than the req time as we have a delay of 1000ms
            {
                clearInterval(counter);
                var modal2 = document.getElementById('booking-modal-2');
                if (modal2.style.display !== 'block') {
                    $("#booking-modal").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#booking-modal").css("display", "block");
                }
                return;
            }
            // document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
        }

}
});
```

Comment: How are you setting the cookie? That's kind of important. For example if you have the `httpOnly` flag on it then obviously JS won't be able to read it - but we can't know that without the setting code.

Comment: I set the cookie via PHP, setcookie('mycookie', $tempToken, time()+ 60 * 60, '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);
  $return = true;

Comment: Oh look, you're setting the `httpOnly` flag. How did I guess? XD

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I've changed TRUE, TRUE to NULL, NULL

Comment: Well that just makes it insecure. You want to set `true` on the secure parameter, and `false` on the httpOnly one.